# How do I find out which version of Java I am using Perl?

Tags: java, perl

How do I find out which version of Java I am using Perl programming and using that execute some jar file based on that?

Comment: When you are using Perl, you are not using Java.  Also, it's possible to have multiple versions of Java installed, but how you determine which is the default is system-dependent.

Comment: It sounds like he wants to execute a jar file "based on" which Java version he is using.. so I'm thinking he has a few jar files for compatibility with different java versions. I don't know any Perl so I can't help though, but hopefully this will make it clearer to someone who does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a perl script,

```
@args = ("java", "-version");
system(@args) == 0
    or die "system @args failed: $?"
```

or rather simply,

```
system("java -version");
```

Comment: Won't this just print the version out to the console without capturing it?  I'm quite rusty at Perl, but I think if he wants to use the result he'll need to capture it with backticks.

Comment: @Bill: you are correct. I'm not sure why the OP accepted this answer without testing it first.

Comment: @Bill I'm doing the same test and running `$capture = \`java -version>&1\``, but it won't capture anything and I get 0 for $? any help is appreciated

Comment: @Eric: What does the `>&1` at the end do?  Can you try it without that and see what you get?  (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 5):

You can capture the Java version from a Perl script using backticks.

```
$version = `java -version`;
```

Also see: [How can I capture STDERR from an external command?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command%3F) for more alternatives than you can shake a stick at.

Comment: the `>&1` is to redirect STDERR, but I tried it both ways. In either senario I get **$version = ""**

Answer (score 0):

```
use IO::Handle;

open OUTPUT, '>', "output.txt" or die $!;
STDERR->fdopen( \*OUTPUT, 'w' ) or die $!;

print `java -version`;
```

Comment: For some reason, Java's -version goes to STDERR on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

"java -version" will show you the version you are using.

"perl -v" will show you the version of Perl you are using.

Comment: If this is how you do it _using perl_, how would you do it without perl?

Answer (score -1):

Use the System command...

```
system("java -version");
```

If you are going to export a new Java

```
system('export PATH=/usr/java1.6/bin:$PATH');
```

Comment: `export` run from a `system()` call will not remain in effect after it ends.